Problem with the password of the GNU Grub recovery mode
So earlier today I decided that I would improve the security of my Ubuntu 22.04 device a bit by adding a password for the recovery mode(GNU Grub). I read a couple of blogs and I followed them step by step. After I was done I rebooted my system to test it out, only to find that I had been locked out of my device. I couldn't boot any option without it prompting me to enter a username and password. I did not know why this happened, but after a bit of research, I realised that I had forgotten to make an encrypted password and I had only did the last parts of the designated script, which was to make the system prompt you to enter the username and password every time you boot up recovery mode. I am now locked out of my device because of an unknown grub password. If you don't set a password for grub, is there a default password or something?

You will need to boot the system from your install media USB device. (At least not the target OS.)
Select trial Ubuntu.
From a command prompt: -
Identity the Ubuntu partition on your target disk
sudo fdisk -l

Then mount it (replace x & y with your Ubuntu details)
mount /dev/sdxy /mnt

Then goto the grub boot directory
cd /mnt/boot/grub

Edit the file as below using your preferred editor (I use vi).
sudo vi ./grub.cfg

Search for password and comment it out.
# password topsecret

Save file; sync the disk and unmount it. Then reboot.
sync; sync
cd /
umount /mnt
reboot


Thank you very much for how to fix this issue once I am booted into the USB. However, how do I boot into my usb? I am stuck on the GNU Grub screen and every option I choose, it prompts me for a username and password.

How did you boot from USB in the past? One way is to make the USB the priority boot device from the BIOS. Another way would be to access the UEFI boot menu from the BIOS and select USB. To access the BIOS you assert one or other key during or just after applying power (DEL, F1, F2, F9?) Sometimes it flashes something on the screen on the method during boot. Assuming you have a UEFI menu this is even more varied. On one machine I had you applied the power while holding down the ESC key. If you can't find this out, type you rig's details into Google and do some research that way. Good Luck.

I have two computers, a desktop and a laptop. They are made by different companies, but I have switched the internal software of both to linux systems. I can boot into my USB from my desktop just fine by accessing the boot menu and make booting from USB priority, but the laptop, which is a Macbook air, probably has a different key I have to press to access the boot menu that I do not know of. I will do a bit of research on it, as that computer was made and distributed in China and it may be different from laptops designed in America.

The following link gives instructions on accessing the BIOS (or equiv) https://cybertechnosys.com/how-to-enter-macbook-air-bios/

Thanks for your help. I successfully booted into USB and fixed my broken grub interface. (It was to restart the PC and hold down alt until you see the interface to boot into USB)
